# Why we can see little light even after main power is off?

Tags: dont-breathe

In Don't Breathe (2016), a blind man turned off the main power so robbers won't find a way out of the basement.

[image]

But we can still see the chracters' movements in the dark, how?

Comment: It's for audience

Comment: I guess that's for dramatization and not the blind person's POV or is it ? I haven't watched the movie yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's for the audience to follow what is going on in the movie.

The characters are completely in the dark (we can see that by their eyes), but the audience wouldn't want to spend 5 minutes just listening to sounds, without realizing how close characters are coming to one another. Using this technique, the audience is kept on the edge as the robbers and blind guy explore the darkness.